# Calling sar in Python is producing weird results

Tags: python, bash, sar

I'm trying to parse sar results in python using subprocess, everytime I call the python code that calls a sar subprocess it produces a different number of lines. 
Here's a minimal program to reproduce this problem:

```
import sys
import subprocess

fn = sys.argv[1]

p = subprocess.Popen(str('sar -r -f %s' % fn).split(' '), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
count = 0
while p.poll() is None:
    output = p.stdout.readline()
    count += 1

print "num lines = %d" % count
```

Calling this program several times, produces different number of lines each time: like this

```
for i in {1..10}; do ./sarextractor.py /var/log/sysstat/sa02; done
```

Calling sar directly on the command line produces constant number of lines:

```
for i in {1..10}; do sar -r -f /var/log/sysstat/sa02 | wc -l; done
```

any idea how can this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose p.poll() returns a return code but the p.stdout buffer still holds some data? Try something like this instead:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
    for line in p.stdout:
        count += 1
```

That will drain the stdout buffer of all its lines.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using poll here, but why not use `communicate`?

```
import sys
import subprocess

fn = sys.argv[1]

p = subprocess.Popen('sar -r -f %s' % fn.split(' '), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
outs, errs = p.communicate()
print("num lines = %d" % len(outs.splitlines())
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Actually both answers are working. I'll give the right answer to the other guy with very few points :)